# Using Google authentication API with PHP

Tags: php, google-api

Instead of printing the userinfo, the following code is printing the details of the access token granted by Google. The code is very simple yet I am not able to figure out the exact cause of this

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$fields = array(
        'code'=>urlencode($_GET['code']),
        'client_id'=>urlencode('###########.apps.googleusercontent.com'),
        'client_secret'=>urlencode('###########'),
        'redirect_uri'=>urlencode('http://######odie.co.in/googlogin'),
        'grant_type'=>urlencode('authorization_code'),
                    );


foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
     $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
     }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);


//close connection
curl_close($ch);
$data =  json_decode($result);

print_r(file_get_contents(' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='.$data['access_token']));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true` to your curl_setopt.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

refer this. its very simple.

[Simple PHP Library for Google Authentication API](http://www.technew.in/forum_thread_621_Google-Authentication-API-Library-with-PHP-for-User-Details.html)